# react-redux can't display my container

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to use `react-redux` and `axios` to get some json data,and update my components,but I've tried many times,it still doesn't work,generated html is like this:

```
<div id="root">
    <simple_result_container data-reactroot=""></simple_result_container>
</div>
```

Here is my code,am i missing something？Please tell me as much as possible,this is very confusing to me,can you explain how can I get and display the json data by using `react-redux`.Any help would be appreciated.

**index.js**

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <simple_result_container ddd="da" />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**simple_result_container.js**

```
@connect(state => state, dispatch => bindActionCreators({get_simple_result}, dispatch))
export class simple_result_container extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const {simple_result_value} = this.props.simple_result_tmp;
        if (simple_result_value === "") {
            this.props.get_simple_result();
        }
    }
    render() {
        const {simple_result_value} = this.props.simple_result_tmp;
        return (
            <div className={bb}>
                <div className="aa">
                    <simple_result_component
                        code={simple_result_value.code}
                        msg={simple_result_value.msg}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component name must be write uppercase.

See [HTML tags vs React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)